# UIWebview blocking main thread, while rendering html5

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit

In my application, I render a HTML5 website using UIWebview.
When I select a drop down, a popover appears with embedded UITableView.
On selecting the entry in table view, JS loads the data.
It seems like Webkit is loading the data synchronously in main thread.
Stack is trace is provided below.
This causes main thread to hang for some time and freezes UI.

I am following UIWebview guidelines, creating the web view on main thread.

Same website works fine on Mobile Safari.
Any help is appreciated.

```
#0  0x3367e004 in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x3367e200 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x3589a3f2 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x3589912a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x3581c4a4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x3581c36c in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x33edd7ca in WebCore::ResourceHandle::loadResourceSynchronously ()
#7  0x33bf5c04 in WebCore::FrameLoader::loadResourceSynchronously ()
#8  0x339ebd5a in WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::loadRequest ()
#9  0x339eb984 in WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::DocumentThreadableLoader ()
#10 0x33b65fd4 in WebCore::DocumentThreadableLoader::loadResourceSynchronously ()
#11 0x33f4880a in WebCore::ThreadableLoader::loadResourceSynchronously ()
#12 0x339eb5bc in WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::createRequest ()
#13 0x339eb35a in WebCore::XMLHttpRequest::send ()
#14 0x339eaeea in WebCore::JSXMLHttpRequest::send ()
#15 0x339ead98 in WebCore::jsXMLHttpRequestPrototypeFunctionSend ()
#16 0x356de598 in JSC::Interpreter::privateExecute ()
#17 0x3575d0ec in JSC::Interpreter::executeCall ()
#18 0x3575ccd0 in JSC::call ()
#19 0x339d5f0e in WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent ()
#20 0x339d5bd2 in WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners ()
#21 0x338dc7c6 in WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners ()
#22 0x338e2d38 in WebCore::Node::handleLocalEvents ()
#23 0x338e2588 in WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent ()
#24 0x338e233a in WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent ()
#25 0x338e230e in WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent ()
#26 0x338e2266 in WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent ()
#27 0x33e757f4 in WebCore::Node::dispatchChangeEvent ()
#28 0x33c278aa in WebCore::HTMLFormControlElement::dispatchFormControlChangeEvent ()
#29 0x33eeb7a8 in WebCore::SelectElement::menuListOnChange ()
#30 0x33eeb7be in WebCore::SelectElement::dispatchBlurEvent ()
#31 0x33c35670 in WebCore::HTMLSelectElement::dispatchBlurEvent ()
#32 0x338e1a4e in WebCore::Document::setFocusedNode ()
#33 0x338e1788 in WebCore::FocusController::setFocusedNode ()
#34 0x33bdfdfe in WebCore::Element::blur ()
#35 0x33b802d0 in -[DOMElement blur] ()
#36 0x358c97e4 in __invoking___ ()
#37 0x358247b0 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#38 0x358243ce in -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] ()
#39 0x306824c0 in -[UIThreadSafeNode forwardInvocation:] ()
#40 0x358c8a82 in ___forwarding___ ()
#41 0x35823650 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#42 0x30511acc in -[UIWebBrowserView resignFirstResponder] ()
#43 0x305e6658 in -[UIWebSelectTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] ()
#44 0x3047bae4 in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] ()
#45 0x304f57aa in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] ()
#46 0x346ad932 in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#47 0x3589aa32 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#48 0x3589a698 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#49 0x3589926e in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#50 0x3581c4a4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#51 0x3581c36c in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#52 0x3559b438 in GSEventRunModal ()
#53 0x303f7e7c in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific on how you are calling the request and passing data into UIWebView?

For example: Have you set the UIWebViewDelegate to control the willStartLoading and didFinishLoading?
Have you set the NSURLRequest to synchronous or asynchronous?

Normally, the delegate loads the UIWebView on a separate thread so that main is not blocked.
I assume you need to work a bit more on certain parameters to get it right.

Comment: Webview is called like this:                          NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0] mutableCopy];
[WebView loadRequest:Request];  
[Request release];

Comment: The delegate is used to track the content loading. The actual loading happens within the UIWebView, which is transparent to us.